# how i can get data from nested array and get the result

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const source = [
    {
      id: "1",
      data: {
          first_name: "Rian",
          last_name: "Nugraha"
      },
      school: {
        id: "1",
        data: "PLMK-JKT"
      },
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      full_name: "Ari Santoso",
      school: {
        id: "1",
        short_name: "GRSR",
        data: "JKT"
      },
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      data: {
        first_name: "Rahman",
        last_name: "Sunggara"
    },
    school: {
        id: "1",
        short_name: "GELM",
        data: "JKT"
      },
    },
    {
        id: "4",
        data: {
            first_name: "Rian",
            last_name: "Nugraha"
        },
        school: {
            id: "2",
            data: "PLMK-BDG"
        },
    },
  ]
```

so, I want to combine first_name and last_name into fullname of the nested array or combine short_name and data in school nested array but always  undefined, the result like below:

{ name : 'Rian Nugraha', school_name: 'PLMK-JKT }

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did using a ternary operator

```js
const source = [
    {
      id: "1",
      data: {
          first_name: "Rian",
          last_name: "Nugraha"
      },
      school: {
        id: "1",
        data: "PLMK-JKT"
      },
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      full_name: "Ari Santoso",
      school: {
        id: "1",
        short_name: "GRSR",
        data: "JKT"
      },
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      data: {
        first_name: "Rahman",
        last_name: "Sunggara"
    },
    school: {
        id: "1",
        short_name: "GELM",
        data: "JKT"
      },
    },
    {
        id: "4",
        data: {
            first_name: "Rian",
            last_name: "Nugraha"
        },
        school: {
            id: "2",
            data: "PLMK-BDG"
        },
    },
  ]
  
  const resArray = source.map((el) => {
    let name = el.data? (el.data.first_name+" "+el.data.last_name): el.full_name;
    let school_name = el.school.short_name? (el.school.short_name+" "+el.school.data): el.school.data;
    const result = {
      name: name,
      school_name: school_name
    }
    return result;
  })
  
  console.log(resArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how to access array @ element (0) and combine first and last names

```
var fullName = source[0].data.first_name + " " + source[0].data.last_name;
```

To add school:

```
var fullNameAndSchool = source[0].data.first_name + " " + source[0].data.last_name + " is from school " + source[0].school.data;
```

Comment: if i want to display all data fullname then i should  use looping for the above condition?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const result = source.map(({data, school, full_name}) => {
    return {name: (typeof data) === "undefined" ? full_name : `${data.first_name + " "+ data.last_name}`, school_name: school.hasOwnProperty("short_name") ? `${school.short_name + " "+ school.data}` : school.data};
});

console.log(result);

/*[
 { name: 'Rian Nugraha', school_name: 'PLMK-JKT' },
 { name: 'Ari Santoso', school_name: 'GRSR JKT' },
 { name: 'Rahman Sunggara', school_name: 'GELM JKT' },
 { name: 'Rian Nugraha', school_name: 'PLMK-BDG' }
 ]*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help provide an example of how to get what you need.

```
const mapfunc = o => ({
  name: `${o.data.first_name} ${o.data.last_name}`,
  school_name: o.school.data
});

source.map(mapfunc);
```

See documentation for Array.prototype.map and string templates.

Answer (score 0):

**if you need first name and last name you can use map method to check each array object and get the specified value using if conditions..**

```js
const source = [
    {
      id: "1",
      data: {
          first_name: "Rian",
          last_name: "Nugraha"
      },
      school: {
        id: "1",
        data: "PLMK-JKT"
      },
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      full_name: "Ari Santoso",
      school: {
        id: "1",
        short_name: "GRSR",
        data: "JKT"
      },
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      data: {
        first_name: "Rahman",
        last_name: "Sunggara"
    },
    school: {
        id: "1",
        short_name: "GELM",
        data: "JKT"
      },
    },
    {
        id: "4",
        data: {
            first_name: "Rian",
            last_name: "Nugraha"
        },
        school: {
            id: "2",
            data: "PLMK-BDG"
        },
    },
  ]
  
  source.map((sources) =>{
  if(sources.data){
  if(sources.data.first_name && sources.data.last_name ) {
    console.log(sources.data.first_name+" "+sources.data.last_name)
    }
    }
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const source = [
    {
      id: "1",
      data: {
          first_name: "Rian",
          last_name: "Nugraha"
      },
      school: {
        id: "1",
        data: "PLMK-JKT"
      },
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      full_name: "Ari Santoso",
      school: {
        id: "1",
        short_name: "GRSR",
        data: "JKT"
      },
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      data: {
        first_name: "Rahman",
        last_name: "Sunggara"
    },
    school: {
        id: "1",
        short_name: "GELM",
        data: "JKT"
      },
    },
    {
        id: "4",
        data: {
            first_name: "Rian",
            last_name: "Nugraha"
        },
        school: {
            id: "2",
            data: "PLMK-BDG"
        },
    },
  ]

for (var i=0; i<=source.length; i++){
  if (source[i]===source[0]){
    console.log("name:" + source[i].data.first_name +" "+source[i].data.last_name + ", school_name: " + source[i].school.data);
  }if(source[i]===source[1]){
    console.log("name: " + source[1].full_name + ", school_name: " + source[1].school.short_name + "-" + source[1].school.data);
  }if(source[i]===source[2]){
    console.log("name:" + source[i].data.first_name + " "+source[i].data.last_name + ", school_name: " + source[i].school.short_name + "-" + source[i].school.data);
  }if(source[i]==source[3]){
    console.log("name:" + source[i].data.first_name +" "+source[i].data.last_name + ", school_name: " + source[i].school.data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).